# Execute readProcess by giving full command

Tags: haskell, command-line-interface

readProcess in Haskell takes command name and its args separately. I'd like to execute command as I have typed it exactly into shell, eg. "ls -la". The main problem is that I have no idea how to execute command with some pipes etc, so

```
./someprogram -s 2> /dev/stdin | grep string
```

seems impossible. I cannot simply pass it into command name, because it throws exception then. So how can I do it?

Comment: System.Process.callCommand

Comment: @amalloy that will not return the stdout of the command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not features you can generally expect the OS or a process library to offer you. They're features of the *shell* language (i.e. `sh`/`dash`/`bash`/`zsh` etc., whatever you use). Thus you have to call the shell as the process, with the entire command as the argument:

```
Prelude System.Process> readProcess "bash" ["-c", "lsusb | grep 'Real'"] ""
"Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:57b5 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. \n"
```

Of course this won't work on a system that doesn't have Bash installed, like Windows.

A nicer approach would be to *not* invoke any shell pipes and `grep`, but do the searching in Haskell itself. The [`turtle`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.3.2/docs/Turtle-Tutorial.html) library makes this easy:

```
Prelude Turtle> :set -XOverloadedStrings
Prelude Turtle> stdout . grep (has "Real") $ inproc "lsusb" [] empty
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:57b5 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

Comment: My purpose was to reach os.popen().read() feature known from Python. It worked without problems there...